# Spring EntityManager.persist issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using a Spring framework (Boot+web+jpa) for a REST service and needs to persist an Entity called `Sensor`. Since I was using Hibernate, I wanted to keep using`EntityManager`. From the Spring Data Access document and some of the questions answered in Stackoverflow, I could see that I should configure `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` or `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Now I was able to read `persist.xml` and persist the entity through dependency injection `@PersistenceUnit(unitName="...") EntityManagerFactory` in case for `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. However, Spring keeps throwing an error everytime when I try to persist `new Sensor()` instance with `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` as shown below.

```
// LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("myunit");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}
```

Persisting (transaction.begin and end are in the caller method):

```
private Sensor getSensor(SimpleData sd) {
    List<Sensor> sensors = entityManager.createQuery("select s from Sensor s where s.deviceId = :devid", Sensor.class)
                                     .setParameter("devid", sd.getDeviceId())
                                     .getResultList();
    Sensor sensor = null;
    if(sensors.isEmpty()) {
        sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.setDeviceId(sd.getDeviceId());
        sensor.setName(sd.getName());
        entityManager.persist(sensor); // Throws an exception
        deviceIdMapper.put(sensor.getDeviceId(), sensor.getId());
        logger.trace("Cannot find the sensor in db, adding: "+sensor.getDeviceId());
    } else {
        sensor = sensors.get(0);
        deviceIdMapper.put(sensor.getDeviceId(), sensor.getId());
        logger.trace("Found a sensor from the db: "+sd.getDeviceId());
    }
    deviceIdMapper.putIfAbsent(sensor.getDeviceId(), sensor.getId());
    logger.trace(sensor);
    return sensor;
}
```

Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [protected int com.database.Sensor.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.database.Sensor#id] : com.database.Sensor@6de9600a
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.persist(Unknown Source)
at com.DataListener.getSensor(DataListener.java:69)
at com.DataListener.lambda$0(DataListener.java:87)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at com.DataListener.processData(DataListener.java:86)
at com.DataListener.onMessage(DataListener.java:49)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1321)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [protected int com.database.Sensor.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.database.Sensor#id] : com.database.Sensor@6de9600a
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4931)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4631)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:540)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.database.Sensor.id to com.database.Sensor
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:594)
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:62)
... 28 more
```

Sensor class:

```
@Entity
public class Sensor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;
    protected String deviceId;
    protected String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SimpleData> simpleDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<SimpleData> getSimpleDevices() {
        return simpleDevices;
    }

    public void setSimpleDevices(List<SimpleData> simpleDevices) {
        this.simpleDevices = simpleDevices;
    }

}
```

There are two questions:

1. Why the error?
2. Spring throws an error if I do not provide `DataSource` for `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`? `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` uses DataSource configs from `persistence.xml` Why `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` doesn't do the same?:

**Edit 1**

I think I have found a solution. If I remove spring-boot-devtools from the dependency, it fixes the problem. In fact when I use spring-boot-devtools I could not read `Sensor` due to some sort of ClassLoader problem. Maybe some sort of a bug?:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.database.Sensor cannot be cast to class com.database.Sensor (com.database.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.database.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6228d409)
```

**Edit 2**
Here is `SimpleData` class

```
@Entity
public class SimpleData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private double value;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Date time;

    @Transient
    private String deviceId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="sensor_id")
    private Sensor owner;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public Sensor getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Sensor owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

Okay, I made a small test program that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/hjparker/spring-boot-devtools-issue.

Once the server is up, you can make a GET request to localhost:8080, which will throw an error. Commenting out spring-boot-devtools in build.gradle will solve the problem. I found this is something to do with the restart classloader in spring-dev-tools (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), which reloads developing code every time spring is restarted. But I think some part of the file is not reloaded automatically causing the classcastexception, e.g. An entity loaded with CL1 != An entity loaded with CL2. Can someone explain if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot at all? Note that your error message specifically refers to your `Sensor` class, which you failed to include.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to include the Sensor class. Yes I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: If you're using Boot, then stop configuring all of the JPA system by hand and just let Boot do it for you. That said, I don't think your Hibernate setup is the problem here; it looks to be something with your class. Try using `Integer` for your ID field (and note that most of the time, if you're using integral types, `Long` is the way to go because 32 bits isn't that much, especially if you have sequences).

Comment: It's better to use wrapper than primitve type so try to use  protected Integer id;

Comment: I think I have found a solution. I needed to remove spring-devtools from the dependencies. But wondering why? If i have devtools and try to read the Sensor class from the DB, the following error occurs.  


    java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.database.Sensor cannot be cast to class com.database.Sensor (com.database.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.database.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6228d409)

Comment: Can you plz show me your SimpleData.class ?

Comment: It is added to the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some of the deserializers for Entity or Bean classes managed by  hibernate/Spring ORM are not reloaded by the spring-boot-devtools restart classloader properly. I had to explicitly include the classes that perform deserialization to the restart classloader by setting the following properties in `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties`:

```
restart.include.hibernate=hibernate.*
restart.include.spring-orm=spring-orm.*
```

Sources:

https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/344

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload

Answer (score 0):

Need to update access modifier private instead of protected, seems that Java persistence tries to get id which is not in package neither is called on some subclass.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String deviceId;
private String name;
```

[Access modifier documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Changed it to private but the result is the same. As I mentioned in the edit, the problem was due to the spring-boot-devtools. I am now wondering what makes this causing the problem. I think it is something to do with two Sensor instances from different ClassLoader due to the addition of spring-boot-devtools.

Comment: It's OK so what can I help you? could you please share your repo?

Comment: I made a small program that produces the problem, please see the updated question.